# Bulk rename (append) CSV files based on a value within

Tags: scripting, rename

Is there a way to rename a batch of CSV files in a folder based on a value within each? I want to take the first value on the second row and append it to the end of the left-hand side. For example:

Filename: 20160101-2015-12-01-20-45-1034581.csv

Contents:

```
HDR,FEC,8.1,FEC Webforms,8.1.0.0,
F1N,C00593228,,JOSH LAROSE SENATORIAL VICTORY SUPER PAC
```

New filename would have a dash and "F1N" added to the end:

New filename: 20160101-2015-12-01-20-45-1034581-F1N.csv

I'm trying to sort through a ton of electronic reports (about 80k files of various sizes), but I need to grab that field to filter out the ones I don't need. Working on a Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script that does it for one file.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

oldname=$1

# create file
printf '%s\n%s\n' \
       'HDR,FEC,8.1,FEC Webforms,8.1.0.0,' \
       'F1N,C00593228,,JOSH LAROSE SENATORIAL VICTORY SUPER PAC' \
       > "$oldname"

# get that "first" value: 
value=$(awk -F, 'NR == 2 {print $1; exit 0}' $oldname)

# insert it into the old name
newname=$(echo $oldname | sed 's/\.csv$/'"-$value&/")

# rename the file
mv $oldname $newname

# show your work ;-)
ls -l $newname
head $newname
```

Testing 1 2 3:

```
$ ./rename foo.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 jklowden  staff  90 Nov 22 20:33 foo-F1N.csv
HDR,FEC,8.1,FEC Webforms,8.1.0.0,
F1N,C00593228,,JOSH LAROSE SENATORIAL VICTORY SUPER PAC
```

You can modify it to be a loop, or write a loop around it.  Personally, I would execute it from **find**(1) as

```
$ find ~/my/csv/files/ -exec ./rename {} +
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like, no matter what file is specified as input, it outputs a file with just the data from the "create file" block. I assume that was there for testing. How to specify the input from the command as the the file to search? 

Also trying to get looping working with **find**.

Comment: @ChrisDC, yes, you should remove the part that creates the file.  **find** doesn't loop, per se; but the `-exec` option executes a command on each found file.  It's a weird utility, but very powerful, and worth struggling with.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to get through all the files very quickly and efficiently!